# How to add custom password in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, plugin

I am wanting to create a password record in the customer_entity table. And after the user creates an inviting account it will save the user password in it.this is my current code
UpgradeSchema.php

```
namespace Magento\PasswordCustom\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $version = $context->getVersion();
        $connection = $installer->getConnection();

        if (version_compare($version, '1.0.0') < 0) {

            $connection->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable('customer_entity'),
                'password_custom',
                [
                    'type'      => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length'    => 255,
                    'nullable'  => true,
                    'default'   => NULL,
                    'comment'   => 'Password Custom',
                ]
            );
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Controller plugin

```
namespace Magento\PasswordCustom\Plugin\Password;

use Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer as ResourceCustomer;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Response;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\FailureToSendException;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class CustomPassword 
{
    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

    /**
     * @var ResponseFactory
     */
    private $_response;

    /**
     * @var Customer
     */
    protected $customer;

    /**
     * @var ResourceCustomer
     */
    protected $resourceCustomer;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManage;

    /**
     * CustomerCreatePost constructor.
     * @param Session $customerSession
     * @param ResponseFactory $responseFactory
     * @param Customer $customer
     * @param ResourceCustomer $resourceCustomer
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManage
     */
    public function __construct(
        Session $customerSession,
        ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        CustomerFactory $customer,
        ResourceCustomer $resourceCustomer,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManage
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession      = $customerSession;
        $this->_response             = $responseFactory;
        $this->customer              = $customer;
        $this->resourceCustomer      = $resourceCustomer;
        $this->storeManage           = $storeManage;
    }
    
    public function afterExecute(CreatePost $createPost, $result)
    {

        $request    = $createPost->getRequest();
        $password  = $request->getParam('password');

        $emailPost  = $request->getParam('email');
        $bind['email'] = $emailPost;
        $customer   = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer();
        $bind['password_custom'] = $password;
        $connection = $this->resourceCustomer->getConnection();
        $sql = $connection->select()->from(
            $this->resourceCustomer->getEntityTable(),
            [$this->resourceCustomer->getEntityIdField()]
        )->where('password_custom = :password_custom')->where('email = :email');
     
        $connection->fetchOne($sql, $bind);
        $customer->save();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost">
        <plugin name="customer_account_create_post_custom" type="Magento\PasswordCustom\Plugin\Password\CustomPassword" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

how can I save this password in the password_custom section I just saved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try code like this one :

```
$customer->setPasswordCustom($password);

$customer->save();

return $result;
```

Comment: I tried before it also didn't work

Comment: 1. Have you check the Password string did you get that password? And which error you are facing on above code?

Comment: main.CRITICAL: Unable to send mail: mail(/usr/local/apache/logs/phpmail.log): failed to open stream: Read-only file system {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\MailException(code: 0): Unable to send mail: mail(/usr/local/apache/logs/phpmail.log): failed to open stream: Read-only file system at vendor/magento/moduleemail/Model/Transport.php:103,Laminas\\Mail\\Transport\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Unable to send mail: mail(/usr/local/apache/logs/phpmail.log): to open stream: Read-only file system at /vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Transport/Sendmail.php:304)"} []

Comment: This message is displayed in var/debug.log and col password_custom do not save https://i.imgur.com/xt0M3Zk.png

Comment: You need to create above fields and customer_eav attribute, not directly as fields of table.

Comment: is there any way i can fix them with observer

Comment: Yes, you can use observer to do the above things. If my answer help you please accept and upvote so it will help other in community.